# How do I update Labels in GTK+-3.0 in C

Tags: c, gtk, label

I can't seem to be able to use the function

```
gtk_label_set_text();
```

this is what I write:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  GtkWidget *label;

  //label
  label = gtk_label_new("This is my label");

  gtk_label_set_text(label, "I cannot use this func");

  if(GTK_IS_LABEL(label)){
    g_print("IT IS A LABEL\n");
  }else if (GTK_IS_WIDGET(label)){
    g_print("well at least its a Widget\n");
  }else {
    g_print("why is it not a label?! T_T\n");
  }

  gtk_main();
  return 0;
}
```

it says

```
passing argument 1 of ‘gtk_label_set_text’ from incompatible pointer type
expected ‘struct GtkLabel *’ but argument is of type ‘struct GtkWidget *’
```

when I try to compile it. OK. I change it to

```
GtkLabel *label;
```

but then it doesn't let me use gtk_label_new(); because the compiler complains with

```
assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

then I give up and comment //gtk_label_set_text   to ask the program   GTK_IS_LABEL(label); and it prints out IT IS A LABEL.
I give up for real now and ask you, dear community of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

As it is C code, you have apply a "cast" your pointer since `gtk_label_new` returns the "base class" or structure:

```
╰── GtkWidget
    ╰── GtkMisc
        ╰── GtkLabel
            ╰── GtkAccelLabel
```

The cast is done through a macro (see [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkLabel.html))
code:

```
GtkWidget *label;

//label
label = gtk_label_new("This is my label");

gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL (label), "I cannot use this func");
```

Note: in C++ no need to cast since `GtkLabel` structure inherits from `GtkWidget`, you could store label in a `GtkLabel` directly, but there's no such thing as inheritance in C.

Comment: The hierarchy is very handy here ++ :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [[ prototype ]](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkLabel.html#gtk-label-set-text) , `gtk_label_set_text` expects 
`GtkLabel*` as its first parameter, so change

```
gtk_label_set_text(label, "I cannot use this func");
```

to

```
gtk_label_set_text((GtkLabel*)label, "I cannot use this func");
```

or more conveniently

```
gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(label), "I cannot use this func");
```

In fact `GTK_LABEL()` macro expands to :

```
#define GTK_LABEL(obj) (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST ((obj), GTK_TYPE_LABEL, GtkLabel))
```

in the header `gtklabel.h`.

Comment: Just to clarify the macro provides extra 'saftey' not just more convenience.

Comment: @TingPing : Well that's correct as apparent from the definition :) Yes !